# WPF: ColumnSpan in UniformGrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout, uniformgrid

I know that *UniformGrid* haven't attached properties *ColumnSpan* and *RowSpan*. But what i really need is container with fixed width and inner cells also with fixed widths, except few UIElements, that should be filled in few cells. 
For example:

```
<UniformGrid Columns="4">   <TextBlock>1</TextBlock>
<TextBlock>2</TextBlock>
<TextBlock Grid.ColumnSpan="2">34</TextBlock>
```

UniformGrid is ideal for me except this situation: last *TextBlock* is not fill two cells.
Is it possible use some other solution to give the needed result? 
Thank you for any advise!

P.S.And... why XAML parser is not stops with error where process this markup?

Comment: For the P.S.: You can set `Grid.ColumnSpan` (and all other attached properties) on any element whenever you like. It just has no effect when the parent of the element is not a Grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a Grid with the columns having varying * widths:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <TextBlock>1</TextBlock>
  <TextBlock Grid.Column="1">2</TextBlock>
  <TextBlock Grid.Column="2">34</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted use only XAML, but for now I still not found the answer. So, i've used following solution: placed all my elements in horizontal WrapPanel and set width for each element in code.